# cannot play sounds on RPI3-B with java

Tags: audio, java, pi4j

im creating a java game library with support for raspberry, on that library I have a class that is in charge of sound effects, I created a game to test GPIO pins and sound was not working, I got an error where it say something like:

"line with format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported" when I tried to play .wav files, I could not hear MP3 background music as well, after thati changed condiguration to ./LCD-hdmi, I ran the game again and this time I could hear MP3 background music and a few sound effects, afert 5 times I got the same exception.

any idea?

Comment: To help you we will need to know more about your configuration, and especially the code you are using to play the audio.

Comment: sure, when i play sounds on the rpi, i can hear only 8 times, after that the clip is closed ( im not sure, i think that ) and i cannot play any sound, and the method im using is "public  synchronized void play(final String fileName)"


you can find the code in the next link: 
https://github.com/pavul/ilusion2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ilusion2/audio/Sound.java  ( DEVELOP BRANCH )

NOTE: this is working well on windows 10 with 8 Gb ram, im checking that on a RPI 3-B with 1 Gb Ram.